# editable TreeViewItem on double click

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, treeviewitem

```
 private void SetCurrentItemInEditMode(bool EditMode)
 {
        if (product_tree.SelectedItem is TreeViewItem)
        {
            TreeViewItem tvi = product_tree.SelectedItem as TreeViewItem;
            // Also make sure that the TreeViewItem
            // uses an EditableTextBlock as its header
            if (tvi.Header is EditableTextBlock)
            {
                EditableTextBlock etb = tvi.Header as EditableTextBlock;

                // Finally make sure that we are
                // allowed to edit the TextBlock
                if (etb.IsEditable)
                    etb.IsInEditMode = EditMode;
            }
        }
    }


error: The type or namespace name 'EditableTextBlock' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

i'm making a TreeView in WPF application. TreeViewItem is fetched from database and i want to make editable treeviewitem when i do double click on TreeViewItem. but i'm getting this error. i searched about this error but couldn't find any good solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me that you have copied some code from elsewhere. The tree view is not editable in WPF. You have copied some code and the class EditableTextBlock can't be found because it does not exist in the PresentationFramework and you haven't added the component referenced in the article you copied from. Generally you get this compile time error when you have not added an assembly reference and/or a using statement to include the class the error refers to.

I guess the first step to including it in your project successfully is to understand how it works in the project that you copied it from.

Comment: yes u r right i copied this code but i want editable treeview and i searched for it. and i got a solution for it here is the link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31592/Editable-TextBlock-in-WPF-for-In-place-Editing

Comment: Yes and the reason you are getting the error is either you have not included the class EditableTextBlock in your project or you do not have a using statement that references the namespace that EditableTextBlock is in.

Comment: it was suggested to use system.windows.control.EditableTextBlock;

Comment: From here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/72544/Editable-Text-Block-in-WPF ? That extends System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock but it will not be in the System.Windows.Controls namespace as this namespace is created by Microsoft. Do you know what a namespace is and how it works?

Comment: yes i know about namespace. it is used to arrange the identifiers refered to http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2010/07/understanding-c-namespaces-and.html i just studied about it

Comment: In your project do you have a class called EditableTreeView?

Comment: no Mr. Mulholland.. i think that class is missing. can u please help me to add EditableTreeView.. thanx in advance

Comment: Sorry I meant EditableTextBlock (the one from the article you are tying to copy) Do you understand how that code works?